# ¿Cómo llevar un resultado de consulta a un modal?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hice este código de inyección MySQL/PDO y no me está reflejando visualmente los datos en el print que tengo declarado después del resultado.
Quisiera saber si encuentran y que puedan explicarme y/o enseñarme cómo llevar esos resultados a un modal Bootstrap.

```
                 try {
                $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$database", $username, $password);
                $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT internacion.historia, padronint.numdoc FROM internacion JOIN padronint ON internacion.historia = padronint.numdoc GROUP BY internacion.historia, padronint.numdoc");
                $stmt->execute();

                } catch(PDOException $e) {
                  echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
                }

                $result1 = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                {
                if (is_array($result1) || is_object($result1))
                  foreach ($result1 as $row)
                  {
                   print "".$row["historia"]." ".$row["numdoc"] ."<br/>";
                  }
                }
```

Comment: y que has intentado pata crear el modal y mostrar los datos???

Comment: nisiquiera indicas con que version de BS estas trabajando...

Comment: Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]